# Getting a partial path to a file in a bash script

Tags: bash, unix, path

I have a path that is stored in a variable

$FULLPATH="/this/is/the/path/to/my/file.txt"

I also have another variable containing a partial path

$PARTIAL="/this/is/the/"

I want to remove the partial path from the full path so that I am left with:

path/to/my/file.txt

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: As is always the case, I solved it 30 seconds after posting. I am running the path through sed and removing the partial path... silly me

Answer (score 3):

Use bash's `#` pattern matching operator:

```
${FULLPATH#${PARTIAL}}
```

Comment: Is there a way to modify this so that there is an optional `/`? That way, if `$PARTIAL` doesn't have the `/`, it will still be removed?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little more detail to Mr. Klatchko's excellent answer:

```
$ FULLPATH="/this/is/the/path/to/my/file.txt"
$ PARTIAL="/this/is/the/"
$ echo ${FULLPATH#${PARTIAL}}
path/to/my/file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that `$PARTIAL` is an actual path:

```
result="${FULLPATH#$PARTIAL}"
result="${result#/}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# echo $FULLPATH | sed 's#'"$PARTIAL"'##'
```